# I want to enter a trade when the price is 3% lower than the previous close

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I want to enter a trade when the price is 3% lower than the previous close.

(close < (close[1]*.97)) - (i tried this but it looks like it's not working)
and

sell automatically 10 days after. - (i don't know the line for this)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct

```
(close < (close[1]*.97))
```

You could even add an extra delay

```
(close[1] < (close[2]*.97))
```

To add a 10 days delay before executing your order, I found a solution here

https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-implement-a-time-delay-between-orders

You'll end up with this delayElapsed variable like in this script

```
var float lastEvent = na
if (close < (close[1]*.97))
    lastEvent := time
delayElapsed = f_timeFrom("bar", 10, "days") >= lastEvent
```